# google colab runtime issue : ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.6.0

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to set the enviroment for my  python notebook on google colab throw exectuing this notebook

```
    !pip3.8 install t5==0.9.0
    !pip3 install tensorflow==2.6.0

    !pip3 install keras==2.6.0
    !pip3 install gin-config
```

I encountred this error :

```
     ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.6.0 (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1)
     ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.6.0
```

The runtime peing used is python3.10. I tried to change it to python3.8 but its not working .

Anyideas how to solve the issue ?

I tried to put text and some pieces of code. I succeded

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install `tensorflow 2.6 (Keras 2.6)` which needs `python version 3.6 to 3.9`  as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu).

Now, Google Colab has been update with python 3.10 which supports only Tensorflow 2.8 to 2.12 (or the latest tensorflow version) which is causing this error. You cannot use fallback runtime in Colab to downgrade the python version to have tensorflow 2.6 installed.

[image]

Please try using the latest tensorflow version between 2.8 to 2.12 to run your code compatible to existing python version in Google Colaboratory to fix this error or you can try installing the required package version using platform(Jupyter, Pycharm etc.) in your local machine.